# Eliminiating duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I work for an organisation which makes house visits, I need to create a query detailing duplicates, the duplicates are indicated by a visit to an address on the same day. My table includes a few of the following fields

```
WorkNo        Address               Appointment Date
54            12 Stackoverflow      12/07/2017
55            12 Stackoverflow      12/07/2017
56            103 London Rd         15/08/2017
57            11 Peterborough Way   19/08/2017
58            12 Stackoverflow      21/09/2017
```

As you can see 2 Work numbers (54 and 55) have been created for the same address on the same day, its these I need to eliminate. Work number 58 is fine because the Appointment date was a different day. Think I'm over thinking it and there's probably a straight forward solution to this but I cant come up with it!

Apologies for the edits and probably the misleading title, I guess i'm not really trying to the eliminate the duplicates in the query, I need to show them, so they can be identified in the report.

```
 WorkNo        Address               Appointment Date
    54            12 Stackoverflow      12/07/2017
    55            12 Stackoverflow      12/07/2017
    78            15 Howards Way        15/07/2017
    79            15 Howards Way        15/07/2017
```

I did previously mention I was working with in SQL Server 2012, however if you could also provide an answer for PostgreSQL as well I would be grateful, thank you

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Do you want to keep the earliest date for each address? the latest? any random one?

Comment: The earliest please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
with hv as (
      select hv.*,
             row_number() over (partition by address, appointment_date order by workno) as seqnum
      from housevisits hv
     )
select hv.*
from hv
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will keep one row of the duplicates.  If you want to actually remove all duplicates, use `count()` instead:

```
with hv as (
      select hv.*,
             count(*) over (partition by address, appointment_date order by workno) as cnt
      from housevisits hv
     )
select hv.*
from hv
where cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CTE to achieve this.

```
WITH CTE AS
(  
SELECT Address, AppointmentDate, row_number() over (partition by Address, AppointmentDate order by Address, AppointmentDate) AS rownum FROM TableName 
)  
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE rownum > 1
```